# How can I rearrange the index level with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The purpose of this post is to try to understand how best to manipulate dataframes with multilevels.

**Create the dataframe**

```
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('WXYZ'))
df['Portfolio']= list('ABCDEF')

df
```

**Dataframe**

```
            Y           Z   Portfolio
01/01/2013  1           2   A
02/01/2013  3           4   B
03/01/2013  5           6   C
04/01/2013  7           8   D
05/01/2013  9           10  E
06/01/2013  11          12  F
```

**Pivot the dataframe**

```
dfs_pivot = df.pivot(columns='Portfolio')

dfs_pivot
```

**Pivoted Dateframe**

```
              Y                         Z  
Portfolio     A   B   C   D   E   F     A   B   C   D   E    F 
2013-01-01    1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
2013-01-02    NaN 3   NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN 4   NaN NaN NaN NaN 
2013-01-03    NaN NaN 5   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN 6   NaN NaN NaN 
2013-01-04    NaN NaN NaN 7   NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN 8   NaN NaN 
2013-01-05    NaN NaN NaN NaN 9   NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  NaN 
2013-01-06    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 11    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 12
```

**How can the levels be switched to give?**

```
Portfolio       A       B       C       D       E        F 
              Y   Z   Y   Z   Y   Z   Y   Z   Y   Z    Y   Z    
2013-01-01    1   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2013-01-02    NaN NaN 3   4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2013-01-03    NaN NaN NaN NaN 5   6   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2013-01-04    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7   8   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-05    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 9   10  NaN NaN
2013-01-06    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 11  12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To swap the order of the MultiIndex levels, use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(6,2)), index=dates, columns=list('YZ'))
df['Portfolio']= list('ABCDEF')
dfs_pivot = df.pivot(columns='Portfolio').swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
```

yields

```
Portfolio     A    B    C    D    E    F    A    B    C    D    E    F
              Y    Y    Y    Y    Y    Y    Z    Z    Z    Z    Z    Z
2013-01-01  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-02  NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-03  NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0  NaN  NaN
2013-01-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0  NaN
2013-01-06  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0
```

---

To sort the columns call [`DataFrame.sortlevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html):

```
dfs_pivot = dfs_pivot.sortlevel(axis=1)
```

yields

```
Portfolio     A         B         C         D         E         F     
              Y    Z    Y    Z    Y    Z    Y    Z    Y    Z    Y    Z
2013-01-01  7.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-02  NaN  NaN  4.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  8.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2013-01-06  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0  9.0
```

---

To rearrange the columns in a custom order, you could call `reindex`:

```
custom_order = [('E', 'Z'), ('D', 'Z'), ('C', 'Z'), ('F', 'Z'), ('F', 'Y'), ('B', 'Z'),
                ('C', 'Y'), ('E', 'Y'), ('A', 'Z'), ('A', 'Y'), ('B', 'Y'), ('D', 'Y')]
dfs_pivot = dfs_pivot.reindex(columns=custom_order)
```

or, more simply, use column-indexing syntax:

```
dfs_pivot = dfs_pivot[custom_order]
```

which yields

```
Portfolio     E    D    C    F         B    C    E    A         B    D
              Z    Z    Z    Z    Y    Z    Y    Y    Z    Y    Y    Y
2013-01-01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2013-01-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN
2013-01-03  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-04  NaN  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
2013-01-05  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-01-06  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: is it possible to name the second row?  `dfs_pivot.columns` yields `MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['Y', 'Z']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['Portfolio', None])`

Comment: `dfs_pivot.columns.names = ['Portfolio','measures']` renames the column and `dfs_pivot.index.names = ['index_date']` renames the index.  `dfs_pivot.index.nlevels`  is also of use for further work.

Comment: Would like to add that the use of `df.pivot_table` allows the use of multiple columns to be pivoted.  This is extremely useful.